# Java attributes

Tags: java, object, attributes

I am trying to build a UML class model for an android game that I have developed. I'm finding it difficult to understand the difference between objects, attributes and operations. Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is to google it and look for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are instances of classes, so think in terms of classes, attributes and operations.

Classes map directly to the UML class.

Attributes are fields or properties of the class.

Operations are logic exposed as methods.  Do not include getters and setters here - they're essentially a work-around for the lack of true properties in Java, and so are already covered in the attributes section.

```
public class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String name,
                  int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person " + name + " is " + age + " years old";
    }
}
```

In UML, this would translate to

**Class** Person

**Attributes** name, age

**Operations** toString

Answer (score 0):

Examples:

Object: Dog, Table, Human, Car ...
Attributes (properties): Arms, Legs, Tires ...
Operations (methods): drive(), bark(), eat(), sleep() ...

Buy a good book to understand the basics of OOP.